# ASP.Net Core installation hangs

Tags: installation, .net-core

I formatted my PC and when I try to get core to create my database, it should extract the core library and then all should be good.

However, the app keeps hanging at "Expanding 100%"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out you have to:

1. Disable anti-virus
2. Open Developer Command Prompt in Admin Mode
3. Run the command "dotnet ef database update"

Running this non admin or in powershell did not work for me